# Call Java Class form JSP Using JSTL library tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have got MyCpu java class which is running fine and I need to display the output into web page I have tried using JSP only and it doesn't work and then I added JSTL tag library and added this code -Djava.library.path="./lib" to MANIFEST.MF 
also I'm using Sigar API and I added to library then I end with this error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuInfoList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo;

Any help or advice please?

```js
package mydata;

import org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class MyCpu {
 private String cpuInfoList;
 public String getCpuInfoList(){
    return this.cpuInfoList;
    }
public MyCpu() {
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
String output = " ";
CpuInfo[] cpuInfoList = null;
try {

cpuInfoList = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
} catch (SigarException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return;
}
for (CpuInfo info : cpuInfoList) {
output += "Vendor: " + info.getVendor() + "\n";
output += "Model: " + info.getModel() + "";
output += "DD:" +info.toString()+ "";
}
System.out.println(output);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
MyCpu main = new MyCpu();
}
}
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   <%@page import="mydata.MyCpu"%>
<%@page import ="org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        
        <%
    MyCpu cpu = new MyCpu();
    Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

out.println(sigar.getCpuInfoList()[4]);
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding it as a JVM argument

```
    -Djava.library.path="./lib"
```

Comment: I have already done that I mean I added but no change .. Thank you